# Nested intervals within PowerShell (c#) / faster alternative to "where-object" with sorted lists?

Tags: performance, powershell, sorting, filtering, where-clause

I'm looking for a way to accelerate the (Windows 10) PowerShell command `Where-Object` for a sorted array.

In the end the array will contain thousands of lines from a log file. All lines in the log file start with date and time and are sorted by date/time (new lines will always be appended).

The following command would work but is extremely slow and ineffective with a sorted array:

```
$arrFileContent | where {($_ -ge $Start) -and ($_ -le $End)}
```

Here is a (strongly simplified) example:

```
$arrFileContent = @("Bernie", "Emily", "Fred", "Jake", "Keith", "Maria", "Paul", "Richard", "Sally", "Tim", "Victor")
$Start = "E"
$End = "P"
```

Expected result: "Emily", "Fred", "Jake", "Keith", "Maria", "Paul".

I guess, using "nested intervals" it should be much faster, like "find the first entry starting with "E" or above and the first starting with "P" or below and return all entries in between.
I suppose there must be a simple PowerShell or .NET solution for this, so I won't have to code it myself, correct?
**Edit 31.08.19:** Not sure if "nested intervals" (German "Intervallschachtelung") is the right term.
What I mean is the "telephone book principle": Open the book in the middle, check if the wanted name is listed before or after, open the book in the middle of the first (or last) half, and so on.
In this case (checking 100.000 lines of a log file for a given date range):
- check line no. 50.000
- if after given start date check line no. 75.000 else check no. 25.000
- check line no. 75.000 (or 25.000)
- if after given start date check line no. 87.500 (or ...) else check no. 62.500 (or ...)
and so on ...
The log file contains lines like this:
    2018-01-17 14:28:19 Installation xxx started
(only with a lot more text)

Comment: You can stack `.where()` methods with different modes that will stop processing once the condition and mode combination are met. An example is `$arrFileContent.where({$_ -ge $start},'SkipUntil').where({$_ -gt $end},'Until')}`. This is faster than what you are doing in every test case for me. But is it fast enough or the most ideal? I don't know.

Comment: the `Group-Object` cmdlet can use calculated props to do the grouping. ///// the `Where-Object` cmdlet is a rather slow bit of code - it has too many things to track - so you may want to use one of the faster techniques. [1] `foreach ($Thing in $Collection)` is usually an order of magnitude faster. [2] the `$Collection.Where()` method is usually at least 50% faster.

Comment: @Lee_Dailey The only problem with the array collection methods is the entire array is loaded in memory to be worked on first.

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1 - yes, that is one reason to use a pipeline. [*grin*] however, debugging things in a pipeline can be truly unpleasant, so one otta start off with simpler structures like the basic `foreach` loop - and only optimize when needed.

Comment: Regarding the edit with log file details, where are these line numbers coming from?  Does line 50,000 somehow reference lines 75,000 and 25,000?  Or are you really trying to do a [binary search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm) by datestamp?  This seems to completely change the nature of the problem, and I don't see how this relates to the "select names where the first letter is in the range `E-P`", which is a really a dynamic range/interval determined by linear search.

Comment: There are no real line numbers or references in the log file.The line numbers only refer to the array which already contains the file content.I tried to simplify the whole problem to make it easier to describe (as stackoverflow help asked for), but in the end, you might be right, this wasn't such a good idea.

Comment: For that matter, you said `$arrFileContent | where {($_ -ge $Start) -and ($_ -le $End)}` would work for this, yet that contains no logic to jump around by halves. It seems to me that the original problem remains "I need to select a range from a large amount of sorted data" and the details in the edit are a proposed solution (binary search) that are turning this into an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). A binary search very well might be a way to solve this, but I would not bias the question with that predetermined outcome if it's not required.

Comment: You're right - that's only my suggestion - but I'm ready to accept any solution as long as it is fast enough! I'll also try Linq ...

Comment: $end is spelled wrong, `$Ende = "P"`

Comment: @js2010: You are (were) right (lost in translation). Corrected!

Answer (score 1):

Let's measure all ways mentioned in comments. Let's mimic *thousands of lines from a log file* using `Get-ChildItem`:

```
$arrFileContent = (
    Get-ChildItem d:\bat\* -File -Recurse -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
).Name | Sort-Object -Unique
$Start = "E"
$End   = "P"

$arrFileContent.Count 

('Where-Object', $(Measure-Command {
  $arrFileNarrowed = $arrFileContent | Where-Object {
    ($_ -ge $Start) -and ($_ -le $End)
    }
}).TotalMilliseconds, $arrFileNarrowed.Count) -join "`t"

('Where method', $(Measure-Command {
  $arrFileNarrowed = $arrFileContent.Where( {
    ($_ -ge $Start) -and ($_ -le $End)
    })
}).TotalMilliseconds, $arrFileNarrowed.Count) -join "`t"

('foreach + if', $(Measure-Command {
  $arrFileNarrowed = foreach ($OneName in $arrFileContent) {
        if ( ($OneName -ge $Start) -and ($OneName -le $End) ) {
            $OneName
        }
    }
}).TotalMilliseconds, $arrFileNarrowed.Count) -join "`t"
```

Output using `Get-ChildItem d:\bat\*`:

```
D:\PShell\SO\56993333.ps1
```

> ```
> 2777
> Where-Object  111,5433    535
> Where method  56,8577 535
> foreach + if  6,542   535
> ```

Output using `Get-ChildItem d:\*` (much more *names*):

```
D:\PShell\SO\56993333.ps1
```

> ```
> 89570
> Where-Object  4056,604    34087
> Where method  1636,9539   34087
> foreach + if  422,8259    34087
> ```

Comment: Even better is foreach () with a break if you're at the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

It is also effective to simply replace as follows

`$arr | where { <expression> }`
↓
`$arr | & { process { if (<expression>) { $_ } } }`

```
$arrFileContent | & { process { if ($_ -ge $Start -and $_ -lt $End) { $_ } } }
```

Comment: There's an extra parenthesis before the if.

Answer (score 0):

"Nested intervals", to me, means "intervals within intervals."  I think I'd describe what you're looking to do is select a *range*.  We can exploit the fact that the data is sorted to stop enumerating as soon as the end of the range is found.

.NET's LINQ queries allow us to do this easily.  Assuming this content for `Names.txt`...

```
Bernie
Emily
Fred
Jake
Keith
Maria
Paul
Richard
Sally
Tim
Victor
```

...in C# the filtering would be as simple as...

```
IEnumerable<string> filteredNames = System.IO.File.ReadLines("Names.txt")
    .Where(name => name[0] >= 'E')
    .TakeWhile(name => name[0] <= 'P');
```

[`ReadLines()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.io.file.readlines) enumerates the lines of the file, [`Where()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.where) filters the output of `ReadLines()` (setting a lower bound on the range), and [`TakeWhile()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.takewhile) stops enumerating `Where()` (and, therefore, `ReadLines()`) once its condition is no longer `true` (setting an upper bound on the range).  This is all very efficient because A) the file is enumerated rather than read entirely into memory and B) enumeration stops as soon as the end of the desired range is reached.

We can invoke LINQ methods from PowerShell, too, but since PowerShell supports neither extension methods nor lamba expressions the equivalent code is a little more verbose...

```
$source = [System.IO.File]::ReadLines($inputFilePath)
$rangeStartPredicate = [Func[String, Boolean]] {
    $name = $args[0]

    return $name[0] -ge [Char] 'E'
}
$rangeEndPredicate = [Func[String, Boolean]] {
    $name = $args[0]

    return $name[0] -le [Char] 'P'
}

$filteredNames = [System.Linq.Enumerable]::TakeWhile(
    [System.Linq.Enumerable]::Where($source, $rangeStartPredicate),
    $rangeEndPredicate
)
```

In order for this to work you have to invoke the static LINQ methods directly and get all of the types correct.  Thus, the first parameter of `Where()` is an `System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable[String]`, which is what `ReadLines()` returns (that's why I used a file for this).  The predicate parameters of `Where()` and `TakeWhile()` are of type `[Func[String, Boolean]]` (a function that takes a `String` and returns a `Boolean`), which is why the `ScriptBlock`s must be explicitly cast to that type.

After this code executes `$filteredNames` will contain a query object; that is, it doesn't contain the results but rather a blueprint for *how to get the results*...

```
PS> $filteredNames.GetType()

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType
-------- -------- ----                                     --------
False    False    <TakeWhileIterator>d__27`1               System.Object
```

Only when the query is executed/evaluated does file enumeration and filtering actually occur...

```
PS> $filteredNames
Emily
Fred
Jake
Keith
Maria
Paul
```

If you are going to access the results multiple times you should store them in an array to avoid reading the file multiple times...

```
PS> $filteredNames = [System.Linq.Enumerable]::ToArray($filteredNames)
PS> $filteredNames.GetType()

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType
-------- -------- ----                                     --------
True     True     String[]                                 System.Array


PS> $filteredNames
Emily
Fred
Jake
Keith
Maria
Paul
```

Comment: Thanks for help. Sorry about the confusion. Obviously I got the wrong translation or didn't describe the problem clearly enough. Are you sure this would also work (and fast) with 100.000 lines which start with a date/time, comparing each date/time with the given range? Wouldn't Linq also have to compare all 100.000 lines (at least in the worst case / depending on the given range) - which would take quite some time? Or can you let Linq know that the array is sorted?

Comment: It would need to be adapted to work with your log files (which are not shown in the question), but, yes, this would be well-suited for selecting a range of records from a large set of sorted data, particularly file data because then you can filter it as its read rather than loading the whole thing into memory.  No, by using `TakeWhile()` it will stop enumerating when it finds an element where `$name[0] -le [Char] 'P'` returns `$false`.  LINQ doesn't need to be told the data is sorted; it's up to the programmer to choose the appropriate methods for their data, which is what I've done here.

Comment: I just edited the problem description and added some more details.

Answer (score 0):

I tried a variation on @josefz's answer.  I didn't get amazing results breaking when I was past the last line I wanted.  Actually, if it was just 'a' to 'b', I save a minute.  Unless the slowness is due to get-content?  "Get-content log" will be slower than "get-content -readcount -1 log".

```powershell
$arrFileContent = Get-ChildItem -name -File -Recurse | select -first 89570 | sort -u

$start = 'e'
$end = 'p'

measure-command {
  $arrFileNarrowed = foreach ($OneName in $arrFileContent) {
    if ($OneName -ge $Start) {
      if ($OneName -le $End ) {
        $OneName
      }
    }
  }
} | fl seconds, milliseconds

# break early
measure-command {
  $arrFileNarrowed = foreach ($OneName in $arrFileContent) {
    if ($OneName -ge $Start) {
      if ($OneName -le $End ) {
        $OneName
      } else {
        break
      }
    }
  }
} | fl seconds, milliseconds
```

Output:

```powershell
Seconds      : 1
Milliseconds : 207



Seconds      : 1
Milliseconds : 174
```

Trying out get-content vs switch -file:

```powershell
$start = 'e'
$end = 'p'

# uses more memory
measure-command {
  $result1 = get-content -readcount -1 log | foreach { $_ | 
    where { $_ -ge $start -and $_ -le $end } }
} | fl seconds,milliseconds

measure-command {
  $result2 = switch -file log {
    { $_ -ge $start -and $_ -le $end } { $_ } }
} | fl seconds,milliseconds
```

Output:

```powershell
Seconds      : 4
Milliseconds : 491


Seconds      : 2
Milliseconds : 747
```

Comment: Reading the file shouldn't be the problem. Although Get-Content is indeed very slow, and there are faster methods (Get-Content -Raw, System.IO.StreamReader, ...) it doesn't matter in this case. Even with 100.000 lines and about 22 MB it takes only 1 or 2 seconds, whereas checking for date range (or else) takes up to 1 minute). My problem arises when the file content has already been read into an array.

Comment: By the way: I created a test file (very similar to my above mentioned log file) like this:`$strLogPath = "c:\temp\test.log"<br>
$strText = " " + "x"*200<br>
$datStart = Get-Date "2019-07-01 00:00"<br>
& {foreach ($intCount in @(1..100000)) {<br>
    $datStart.ToString('yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss') + $strText<br>
    $datStart = $datStart.AddMinutes(1)<br>
}} | Set-Content -Path $strLogPath -Encoding UTF8<br>
`

Comment: Hmm, even with your sample,  `| where` only takes 1.9 sec with `$start = '2019-07-14 21:19'; $end = '2019-08-11 15:59'`, 20% and 60% into the file.  `foreach ()` with a `break` wins at 286 ms.  @josefz